# Get company name in google sheets using stock ticker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, stock, yahoo-finance, custom-function

I have a google sheet getting stock information by symbol. I found this code below to get prices but don't really understand how it's working.

```
function yahooF(ticker) {
  const url = `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/${ticker}?p=${ticker}`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  const contentText = res.getContentText();
  const price = contentText.match(/<fin-streamer(?:.*?)data-test="qsp-price"(?:.*)>(\d+\.\d+)<\/fin-streamer>/);
  console.log(price[1]);
  return price[1];
}
```

Does anyone know a way using a similar method to get specifically the company name, but understanding how to use this to get other data would be great. I'm not interested in using =GOOGLEFINANCE functions as they seem to fail pretty often.

Comment: Instead of the match function which is very specific to one piece of information, you should parse the json to get about 15,000 pieces of information from the source at once. The difficulty is then to detail them all.

Answer (score 0):

Try, by parsing the json inside the source

```
function yahooFNameOfCompany(ticker) {
  const url = `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/${ticker}?p=${ticker}`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText();
  var jsonString = res.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  console.log(data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData[ticker].shortName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use GOOGLEFINANCE("stock_exchange:ticker", "name")
e.g. =GOOGLEFINANCE ("NASDAQ:GOOG", "name") you should be getting reliable results